# sequential ploting (e.g. real time data plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a simple stream of data coming sequentially (ie, a time dependent variable) but I could not get any output. I therefore tried different "solutions" proposed for real time plot in stackoverflow... but all I get is again no plot at all.
I looked at the cookbook on animations (http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations) and tried one of the given examples as well, reproduced here below:

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()

tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))
for i in arange(1,200):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas

print 'FPS:' , 200/(time.time()-tstart)
```

Again, I got no graph output... just the final print.
Can someone tell me why all the examples supposedly working, are actually not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in iPython notebook (python 2.7).

Maybe you want to make sure your back-end setting for pylab is not set to inline?

[you'll likely have to restart your kernel for the changes to take effect]

Another possibility is that your process is still running from a previous attempt.

Comment: Interesting. So this works for you. I use Spyder 2.1.13 with python 2.7.3 64 bits under linux fedora 17. What do you mean by make sure the 'backend setting for pylab is not set to inline?' how can I check this. Thanks anyway for your reply.

Comment: In iPython notebook, you set '%pylab' instead of '%pylab inline' (must restart the kernel) - in your IDE, there should exist a convenient menu for you to do this.

Comment: It could be indeed a problem with the backend. However, after having listed all backends (with plt.get_backend()), I tried all my available backends ( e.g. the command switch_backend('CocoaAgg')). But this does not change anything. I also tried to kill all process related to python and spyder, and restart everything (to be sure that no older process was still running) but it does not help either. Small note* plotting works fine if I use plt.show()... but I cannot do any realtime then...

Comment: I fired up spyder (never used it before, maybe I should, it looks nice); there is a preferences menu (looks like a toolbox) in the header; it opens a popup where you can choose iPython, graphics or display' maybe you can play with this and see if you can make it work? Sorry I cannot be of more help.